# Is there a way to reference a cell in a range reference?

Tags: excel

I am trying to write an if statement to return yes or no when a value is equal to a list of values whose number of rows is variable.
example
1   ha
1   ha
1   ha
1   ha
2   ha
2   ha
2   he

so this statement would return no for the 1's and yes for the 2's

so far i created a `countif(a:a,a1)`(lets say this value is in c1) to count the number of 1s and 2s but for the next column I want to use `if(c1=countif(b1:b(1+c1-1),b1, "no", "yes")`(the b(1 will change but the -1 stays the same). I don't think that works but is there any way for me to do what I want to do.

Comment: Could you update your query with a screenshot if possible with an expected output, so that it helps better understanding and providing solutions accordingly as far i think you might need `SUMPRODUCT` Function here!

Comment: so if all the 1's are ha i expect no, otherwise yes. since there is a he mixed in with the ha in 2 we get yes. part of the problem is the fact that the number of rows will be variable so we have to calculate that for each "group". The first column is numbers, the second is chars and the third is boolean yes or no.

Comment: Try using the `SUMPRODUCT` Function,

Comment: =IF(AH5=SUMPRODUCT((O:O=O5)*(Q:Q=Q5)*AH:AH), "NO","YES") this gives me a N/A error

Comment: Check if this works `=IF(AH5=SUMPRODUCT(--(O:O=O5)*--(Q:Q=Q5)*AH:AH), "NO","YES") ` `--` refers to double unary

Comment: Still not working :(. o column is a reference number, Q is a type of product, and AH is just the total number of the same reference numbers in column o. IDK if that helps

Answer (score 0):

In the end the answer was simple

=IF(COUNTIF(O:O, O5)=(COUNTIFS(O:O,O5,Q:Q,Q5)),"NO","YES")